# Lua/Box2D: Apply velocity in a direction

Tags: lua, physics, box2d

How do I apply velocity in a forward direction relative to an object's current velocity using Lua and Box2D?

I'm trying to figure this out. Here's what I have so far: to get the object's current velocity vector, you need to subtract its last position from its current position. Then I can apply that to the object's velocity somehow. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box2D supplies a function `b2Vec2 GetLinearVelocity()` that you can use to get the velocity of a body. There is also `SetLinearVelocity(const b2Vec2&);` that you can use to apply a velocity.

How this all ties in to your Lua code is up to you. Without more information there's not much advice I can give you for that.